# Not working - Debug Mode native code (c/c++) on Android studio with tablet HUAWEI MediaPad M5

Tags: android, debugging, native, mode, huawei-mobile-services

I have a problem when i put breakpoints on my native code (c/c++) with this tablet (HUAWEI MediaPad M5, android 8.0.0, processor Hisilicon Kirin 960s).
Indeed, in debug mode, i can't use the breakpoint on native code. So i can't debug native code. 
It's working with all the others devices (smartphone : samsung, sony).
The setup configuration on android studio is ok.
Can you help me please ? Do you have any solution please?

Thanks you,

Best regards

Comment: I have the same issue here. Running a Huawei P10. I can debug on other phone without issue.

Comment: The same problem with Huawei Honor 10.

Comment: Same here, HUAWEI P20.

Answer (score 2):

Well, We contact HUAWEI's tech support and they told us that this is intended, probably on security purpose.
Good news is that they can flash the ROM to a dev edition. Maybe you can contact them too.

EDIT: The symptoms: breakpoints cannot be set, and call stack has lots of unknown frames.